# Cannot access to CentOS from MS Windows via http

Tags: linux, apache, http, configuration, centos

I have got installed CentOS 7 under virtual envirment.
It has proper  hostname so I can ping it and it has acccess to internet inside of it and I can ping by IP and host name outside of it. Also It has working Apache and its test page is fine that has been checked locally.

Now I would like to get access to this test page from the MS Windows but I cannot. (I can ping CentOS by IP and hostname.)

Has it something to do with `Iptables` or `firewall`?

[image]

And this link doesnt help as well https://serverfault.com/questions/459267/enabling-http-access-on-port-80-for-centos-6-3-from-console

I assume some settings should be changed under CentOS but I am not sure which of them.

My question is which steps I have to execute to allow all those things?

Comment: Since the release of RedHat/CentOS 7, the previous firewall system has been replaced with firewalld. http://serverfault.com/questions/616435/centos-7-firewall-configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either disable firewalld.service

```
systemctl disable firewalld.service
systemctl stop firewalld.service
```

Or allow access to port 80

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Also disable SELINUX:

```
setenforce 0
sed -i 's/^SELINUX=enforcing/SELINUX=disabled/' /etc/sysconfig/selinux
```

Comment: Hi! Please take a look at the my iptables that I just added. About  firewall command it says `FirewallD is not running`. An d bout `setenforce 0` is says  `setenforce() failed`. Any clue?

Comment: Can you telnet to CentOS port 80 from windows? What is `getenforce` o/p?

Comment: No,  I can not connect. It says is imposible to open connection.

Comment: if firewall is not running. then it could be a problem with Selinux. edit `/etc/sysconfig/selinux` to disable SELINUX and reboot the server if `getenforce` o/p is `Enforcing`

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is a simple one.

I just used Firewall settings to allow http and httpd.