# No access to nodeJS App via IP in CentOS VPS

Tags: node.js, nginx, centos, vps, centos7

I've implemented a simple nodeJs app on CentOS 7 (VPS)
The program is executed on the server but not visible in the Client browser.
I looked nginx and Python code to set up the server but not through IP observed.
Do I need to do server specific settings.

my nodeJS app:

```js
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 5050
http.listen(port, function(){
 console.log(process.env);
  console.log('listening on *:5050');
});
```

Output:

```js
[root@localhost realupdater]# node test.js
{ XDG_SESSION_ID: '43',
  HOSTNAME: 'localhost.localdomain',
  SELINUX_ROLE_REQUESTED: '',
  TERM: 'xterm',
  SHELL: '/bin/bash',
  HISTSIZE: '1000',
  SSH_CLIENT: '194.225.33.194 3352 22',
  SELINUX_USE_CURRENT_RANGE: '',
  SSH_TTY: '/dev/pts/0',
  USER: 'root',
  LS_COLORS: 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=01;36:*.au=01;36:*.flac=01;36:*.mid=01;36:*.midi=01;36:*.mka=01;36:*.mp3=01;36:*.mpc=01;36:*.ogg=01;36:*.ra=01;36:*.wav=01;36:*.axa=01;36:*.oga=01;36:*.spx=01;36:*.xspf=01;36:',
  MAIL: '/var/spool/mail/root',
  PATH: '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin',
  PWD: '/root/realupdater',
  LANG: 'en_US.UTF-8',
  SELINUX_LEVEL_REQUESTED: '',
  HISTCONTROL: 'ignoredups',
  SHLVL: '1',
  HOME: '/root',
  LOGNAME: 'root',
  SSH_CONNECTION: '194.225.33.194 3352 185.81.96.119 22',
  LESSOPEN: '||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s',
  XDG_RUNTIME_DIR: '/run/user/0',
  _: '/usr/local/bin/node',
  OLDPWD: '/root' }
listening on *:5050
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4uSv.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34068424/5615242)

Either disable firewalld.service

```
systemctl disable firewalld.service
systemctl stop firewalld.service
```

Or allow access to port 80

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Also disable SELINUX:

```
setenforce 0
sed -i 's/^SELINUX=enforcing/SELINUX=disabled/' /etc/sysconfig/selinux
```